# Посоветуйте рабочий пример использования phpWord

Tags: php, phpword

Подскажите у кого есть опыт работы phpWord, по какой документации его можно использовать на виртуальном хостинге?

Пробовал базовый пример из официальной документации https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#basic-example - он не работает. Просто ничего не происходит и ошибок нет.

Урок, который на многих сайтах дублируется, но довольно старенький судя по всему https://webformyself.com/phpword-sozdanie-ms-word-dokumentov-sredstvami-php/ - если шаг за шагом повторить то документ создается, но не открывается, Word выдает ошибку "К сожалению не удается открыть файл first из-за проблем с его содержимым. Файл поврежден поэтому его нельзя открыть".

Посоветуйте хороший простой рабочий пример использования данной библиотеки. Спасибо!

P.S. Версия PHP 7.3. Версия Composer и пакета phpWord последняя на текущую дату. Используется CMS Joomla и CCK Seblod. Виртуальный хостинг SpaceWeb.

Comment: Проверьте, включен ли на сервере модуль для работы с ZIP

Comment: Как это проверить?

Comment: Вероятно включен ведь по второй из инструкций документ создается. Только не открывается